# How to paint an X11 Pixmap using Qt5

Tags: qt, x11, qt5, qpixmap

I'm trying to draw an X11 Pixmap to a `QWidget`.

In the past using Qt4.x I would leverage `QPixmap::fromX11Pixmap` to create a `QPixmap` that I could easily use in painting. However this function has been removed in Qt5 and from my knowledge the functionality has not been made available elsewhere in the Qt Framework.

While I have been able to create and allocate the X11 Pixmap I haven't been able to find any solution to perform the painting. Any suggestions/solutions welcomed!

Comment: If you want to capture the screen, you can use `QScreen::grabWindow`; I *guess* you can use any `Drawable` in that function but I have never tried.

Comment: @n.m. `QScreen::grabWindow` uses the X11 `XGetWindowAttributes` function in its implementation. Any experience using this function with an `XPixmap`? The documentation for `XGetWindowAttributes` says it can report `BadWindow` when "A value for a Window argument does not name a defined Window." So not entirely sure if using an `XPixmap` would work as its a `Drawable` not a `Window`. I'll give that a try and post the outcome.

Comment: OK so then it's probably not possible to use any drawable. I don't understand why one would use X11 pixmaps as image sources though; care to share?

Comment: @n.m. We use a third party product that renders into a X11 pixmap to allow us to perform additional painting, overlays with drop shadows, buttons, etc... We're in the process of migrating away from this solution but for the time being we're stuck with X11 pixmaps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and didn't find any answer. After doing some hacks I came to this solution.

```
// Initialize your X11 enviroment.
Display* display ...
Pixmap pixmap ... 
/* Do your pixmap drawing HERE */
// Make sure all drawing have been done
XFlush(display);
// Convert your Pixmap to XImage
XImage *image = XGetImage(display, pixmap, 0, 0, width, height, 0xFFFFFFFF, ZPixmap);
// Convert XImage to QImage
QImage tempImage = qimageFromXImage(image);
// Destroy temporal XImage
XDestroyImage(image);
// Finally create a QPixmap
QPixmap finalPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(tempImage);
```

The code for function `qimageFromXImage(...)` can be found at https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/plugins/qt/QtX11ImageConversion.h
You can copy the header and implementation to your source tree.

Problem solved! Can be used with a QQuickPaintedItem or QGraphicsItem.